# Find the inverse function of $ f(v) = \frac{m_0}{\sqrt{1 − {v^2/c^2}}}$ and explain its meaning.

Tags: calculus

In the theory of relativity, the mass of a particle with speed $v$

$$m = f(v) = \frac{m_0}{\sqrt{1 − {v^2/c^2}}}$$
where $m_0$ is the rest mass of the particle and $c$ is the speed of light in a vacuum. Find the inverse function of $f$ and explain its meaning.

I tried to solve for the inverse of the function and I got $$f^{-1}(v) = c\sqrt{1-m^2/v^2}.$$ I'm not confident in my answer

Can someone please help me. I'm really confused. What does this mean?

Comment: Your answer is wrong.  If $f$ is a function that takes $v$ and gives you $m$, then $f^{-1}$ should be a function that takes $m$ and gives you back $v$.  So at the very least it should be $f^{-1}(m)$, not $f^{-1}(v)$.  And $v$ should not appear in the definition of $f^{-1}$, because you are supposed to get $v$ back out. I think you should take the initial equation $$m = \frac{m_0}{\sqrt{1-v^2/c^2}}$$ and try again to solve for $v$ in terms of $m_0$ and $m$.  That means you should end up with something of the form $v = \ldots m_0\ldots m\ldots$.

Comment: That's what I tried doing though

Comment: The answer you posted still has $v$ on the right-hand side.  You're supposed to try to get $v$ on the left-hand side all by itself.  And where did $m_0$ go?  It vanished completely; that can't be right.  If you show us your work, someone might point out your specific error, but as it seems to be a problem with your algebra, the only other thing we could do is to solve the problem for you.  So I suggest you start over from scratch and try again.

Answer (score 2):

Since relativistic mass is a function of velocity, $$m(v) = \frac{m_0}{ \sqrt{1 - \frac{v^2}{c^2}}}$$
If you want it inverse, 
$$v(m) = c \sqrt{ 1 - \frac{m_0^2}{m^2 }}$$
There isn't any particular interpretation of the $v(m)$. It's just answer to the question, an object with rest mass $m_0$ starts moving and you measure it's new mass to be $m$, what would be it's velocity. Or at what velocity should an object move such that from your reference frame you measure it's mass to be $m$. An object with non zero rest mass to move with speed of light, you need that relativistic mass to be measured as infinite or particles with rest mass zero moves with speed of light as mentioned by MJD on comments.

Comment: One thing that might be worth noticing is that if $m_0 = 0$ then $v(m) = c$. That seems to me to have some interesting physical ramifications.

Comment: @MJD yes ... lol, the rest mass for photon (light) is zero and light travels with the speed of light.

Comment: More general than that: *anything* with a zero rest mass must always travel at velocity $c$.  Photons are only one example.

Comment: @MJD thanks for pointing it out